# Did Lalo do this to the innocent couple in S6E01?

Tags: character, better-call-saul

In S06E01, we see Lalo going to a couple's home after the events of last season.

It seems the couple knows Lalo and offered him coffee and talks with him about how he helped the family. And then we see Lalo catching the scissors as if to kill the woman, but it is not shown, and then it cuts to him going to the bathroom where the women's husband is shaving his beard and he sees him, both laugh and it cuts again. Nothing is shown about them afterward.

So did Lalo kill them? If so why when he helped them so much?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, because [he needed the body of the man](https://www.insider.com/better-call-saul-season-6-premiere-lalo-detail-you-missed-2022-4):

> Needing a body to make his death look believable to Gus and the world, Lalo finds a man who closely resembles himself. He then encourages this man to shave his facial hair in a way that makes him look like Lalo's double.
>
> Moments before Lalo kills the man off-screen, there's a shot where the man looks up at Lalo and you're supposed to notice that the two look very similar.

As pointed out by Miloslaw Smyk in the comments, and [backed by this article](https://screenrant.com/better-call-saul-lalo-body-double-dental-records-terrifying/):

> Furthermore, **paying for Mateo's dental treatments shows he also uses actions to back that up**. The manipulation of Mateo and Sylvia adds another layer of villainy to Lalo, as it proves **he's willing to prey on the struggles and naivety of innocent people to get what he wants** before happily disposing of them when need be.

Comment: Also, a part of the conversation is about a dentist who helped the man with his teeth. "Your dentist worked so hard!", says his wife. Later, when Tyrus is briefing Gustavo about the killings in Mexico, he comments "It all checks out. Dental records, too". The implication is that Lalo noticed man's similarity to himself long time ago, and was "grooming" him as a potential body double for future use.

Comment: @MiloslawSmyk Didn't really register the dentist talk, I just imagined the report was falsified. In fact, I thought it was a bit odd that Gus just took that information at face value when presented to him when my first instinct was "well obviously the coroner has been paid off to say that."

Comment: I didn't pick up on the dental thing when I watched the episode, but it's confirmed in [the behind-the-scenes podcast about the episode](https://play.acast.com/s/bettercallsaul/304-better-call-saul-insider). I guess if you've got a hydraulic bath with an escape tunnel underneath, you're the kind of guy who plans for many eventualities.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: Lalo is indeed a planner -- probably the most intelligent of all the characters in both shows, except I wonder why he does not take his vast fortune and quit the business -- unless one is not allowed to do such a thing. Only a little reflection shows none of the villains lived a life worth living unless they actually enjoyed the extreme danger, which in Lalo's case seems very possible -- many opportunities for violence which he I think he may have liked for its own sake.

Comment: @releseabe Lalo’s not in the fortune business. He’s in the empire business.